# Can I force the "From" to international sms numbers

Tags: notifications, sms, twilio

I have created an application that that sends error notifications to some mobile numbers located inside and outside of the United States via Twilio.

Inside the United states I get the expected results. The message shows that it is coming from my Twilio assigned phone number. However, when I test to an international destination; the results are unpredictable.

Sometimes I receive the message "from" a long number that is almost never the same twice. Other times I receive the message "from" a meaningless and sometimes strange "short code" that changes frequently as well.

How can I prevent this unwanted, unpredictable behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Customer Support here - this is not really a stack overflow question as its to do with the way carriers send SMS in certain markets, but if you write into the help@twilio.com we'll explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Different countries actually have different policies about sender IDs. In some countries you are able to deliver A2P traffic only from alpha senders, for example. In other countries you might be able to send messages only from a local longode sender ID or from a shortcode like in USA. There are also often different routes available which may support different features. If you would like to test out features of the route your current SMS supplier has, you can send test SMS messages on mobile test numbers of telqtest.com