# Manage Twilio Opt-out/in

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm integrating Twilio for SMS message delivery.

I've successfully came to receive the SMS in my personal phone number, and also I could receive and process the status callbacks for handling the SMS state transition (using ngrok).

This is the request for creating a message I use:

```
HTTP POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/<my-account-id>/Messages.json
From:+1205543....
Body:Hi Martin
To:+549116522....
StatusCallback:https://c083-186-19-250-66.ngrok.io/Twilio/callback
```

When I receive the message in my personal cellphone, it's sent from a short code (I don't manage it, and it varies in different requests).
I tried answering immediately: STOP, STOPALL and others, but I keep receiving messages if I do the same request. I can't see any log in Twilio's console message logs. Then, the opt-out doesn't seem to be working.

I want to catch the opt-out and opt-in for managing a blocked list in my application.
I tried to add the Webhook uri (the same as status callback) in the messaging section in the Twilio's configuration section for the phone number I use as sender. Though, I'm not receiving any callback.

[image]

I've dug into [this documentation](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-) but I couldn't find response for my issue.

I've also tried the same with Messaging Services (instead of using From, used MessagingServiceId in the form request). However, the results are the same, I don't receive the opt-out notification, nor in the status callback url (parameter), neither in the url set in the webhook shown above (selected Messaging Service created in the dropdown list).

Hope somebody could help me with this issue soon.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because you use a US number to send a message to a Argentinian number.

Sender ID policies vary across countries. Some countries allow A2P traffic only from alpha senders, while others require messages to be sent from a local longcode sender ID or a shortcode, such as in the USA. Additionally, different routes may offer varying features. (also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888718/can-i-force-the-from-to-international-sms-numbers))

And since you are not the operator of this short code, which is shared by multiple customers, users cannot mute it and you cannot receive replies.

I would suggest use another sender ID from another country to communicate with Argentinian numbers.

Comment: Hi IObert, thanks for your response. 
The application I'm working in pretends to work internationally to notify news to our users through SMS. Thus, I need to provide a mechanism to allow them to decide if they want to stop being notified. In this case, I need to buy a short code for that purpose, isn't it? I tried to access telqtest.com but I couldn't reach from Argentina. Is there a way I can test the opt-in/opt-out until I have this exclusive short code?

Comment: I tested sending to an US number but sms is not being delivered. It fails with this [error](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30034).